# How to Serve a Video (blob) with Google App Angine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, video-streaming, html5-video, blobstore

I'm trying just for learning how to serve a video with the blobstore without it takes all the screen the video, for example

here I imported Video as video_model

```
class ViewVideo(webapp.Reque...,blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):

  def get(self):
    video_id = self.request.get('video_id')
    video_instance = None        
    if video_id:
        video_instance = video_model().get_video_content(video_id)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4' 
        self.send_blob(video_instance.content.key())            

class Video(db.Model):

  content = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
  title = db.StringProperty()

  def get_video(self,video_id):
    return Video.get_by_id(video_id)


  def get_video_content(self,content):
    query_str = "SELECT * FROM Video WHERE content =:content"
    return db.GqlQuery(query_str,content=content).get()
```

Where the video_id came from a url given, but as you see I put it directly in send_blob() function and this one when I tested it takes all the screen just to see the video, I was wondering how can I serve the video from my application without happening this, I was thinking embedded HTML but I can't figure it out how the source will be

Any help will be grateful

If it lacks of content to answer the question I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Without HTML5, it's a tricky mess.  **With** HTML5, it becomes easy & elegant.  Serve to the user's browser, as part of whatever page you're serving, the following HTML (5) snippet:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/getmp4?video_id=whatever" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag: please upgrade it!
</video>
```

and use that `ViewVideo` handler to serve only the `/getmp4` URL, not the URL that your user directly gets via their browser.

The `320`, `240`, and the choice to show `controls`, are all optional, of course -- as even more is the use of `whatever` for the video id!-)